# Altair Line Plot with Two Lines and Log-Scaled Y-Axis

Tags: python, plot, logarithm, altair, line-plot

I have this dataframe:

```
    btc_yields  Year    reit_yields
0   3619143193  2010    -3093
1   45790476    2011    -1833
2   37433124    2012    -1632
3   2739779     2013    13984
4   808407      2014    22776
5   1711472     2015    21642
6   685726      2016    21023
7   75958       2017    19760
8   49428       2018    20704
9   34330       2019    24687
10  27005       2020    21701
```

And I have generated this plot of btc_yields by year:

[image: plot]

Using this code:

```
btc_yield_chart = alt.Chart(btc_yields_df).mark_line(color = 'orange', strokeWidth = 7).encode(
    x = alt.X('Year:N', title = 'Buy-in Year'),
    y = alt.Y('btc_yields', title = 'Yields in USD ($)', scale=alt.Scale(type='log')),
    tooltip = 'btc_yields'
).properties(
    width = 600,
    height = 400,
    title = 'Return on $10,000 Seed Investment in Bitcoin by Buy-in Year'
).configure_axis(
    labelFontSize=14,
    titleFontSize=16
).configure_title(
    fontSize = 21
)
btc_yield_chart
```

I'd like to use a layered plot to include the reit_yields as another line in the chart and have tried this to no avail:

```
base = alt.Chart(merged_btc_reit_low_inf).encode(
    x = alt.X('Year:N', title = 'Buy-in Year'),
    ).properties(
    width = 600,
    height = 400,
    title = 'Return on $10,000 Seed Investment in Bitcoin by Buy-in Year'
)
alt.layer(
    base.mark_line(color = 'orange', strokeWidth = 5).encode(
      y = alt.Y('btc_yields', title = 'BTC Yields in USD ($)', scale=alt.Scale(type='log')),
     tooltip = 'btc_yields'
    ),
    base.mark_line(color = 'blue', strokeWidth = 5).encode(
      y = alt.Y('reit_yields', title = 'REIT Yields in USD ($)', scale=alt.Scale(type='log')),
     tooltip = 'reit_yields'
    )
).configure_axis(
    labelFontSize=14,
    titleFontSize=16
).configure_title(
    fontSize = 21
)
```

If I remove `scale=alt.Scale(type='log')` the plot gets generated but since the y-axis is no longer log-scaled the graph is not informative at all. I would like help re-log-scaling the y-axis with this layered format. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The log of negative values is undefined so you would need to [use the symmetric log](https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/docs/scale.html#symlog) instead: `scale=alt.Scale(type='symlog')`. Symlog also defines a linear range around zero to avoid near infinite log transformed values.

Comment: Great, thank you! That worked. I am wondering if there is a way to add more y-axis labels however? The graph only has two y-axis labels at extremely high values, and one at an extremely low value. I have tried `axis=alt.Axis(tickCount=merged_btc_reit_low_inf.shape[0])` within the `alt.Y` of the `alt.layer` code to get 11 ticks, but it does not work. Do I need to do something in the `base` code?

Comment: Replied to this new question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70816564/changing-number-of-y-axis-ticks-in-altair