# Altair repeated chart, add different subplot/chart title

Tags: altair

I can't believe I haven't been able to google the answer for this .... in the documented example of repeated charts, how would I add a **different** sub-chart titles?

```
import altair as alt
from vega_datasets import data
iris = data.iris.url

alt.Chart(iris).mark_point().encode(
    alt.X(alt.repeat("column"), type='quantitative'),
    alt.Y(alt.repeat("row"), type='quantitative'),
    color='species:N'
).properties(
    width=200,
    height=200,
    title="Chart title",
).repeat(
    row=['petalLength', 'petalWidth'],
    column=['sepalLength', 'sepalWidth']
).interactive()
```

adds the same title to each sub-chart. Can I pass in a list of titles here? The figure in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72079597/6395452) shows that the same chart title would show up in all columns. The same seems to be the case for my data/code:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible to change title for repeated charts, but depending on your application you might be able to workaround this by using a transform_fold + faceting instead:

```py
import altair as alt
from vega_datasets import data


iris = data.iris.url

alt.Chart(iris).mark_point().encode(
    alt.X('species:N'),
    alt.Y('value:Q'),
    color='species:N'
).transform_fold(
    ['petalLength', 'petalWidth', 'sepalLength', 'sepalWidth']
).facet(
    'key:N'
)
```

[image]