# Remove repeating values from X axis label in Altair

Tags: python-3.x, altair

I am having trouble with Altair repeating X axis label values.

```
Data:
  rule_abbreaviation  flagged_claim  bill_month
0         CONCIDPROC              1     Apr2022
1         CONTUSMAT1              1     Apr2022
2            COVID05              1     Jun2021
3         FILTROTUB2              1     Sep2021
4         MEPIARTRO1              1     Mar2022
```

#Code to generate Altair Bar Chart

```
bar = alt.Chart(Data).mark_bar().encode(
        x=alt.X('flagged_claim:Q', axis=alt.Axis(title='Flagged Claims', format= ',.0f'), stack='zero'),
        y=alt.Y('rule_abbreaviation:N', axis=alt.Axis(title='Component Abbreviation'), sort=alt.SortField(field=measure, order='descending')),
        tooltip=[alt.Tooltip('max(ClaimRuleName):N', title='Claim Component'), alt.Tooltip('flagged_claim:Q', title='Flagged Claims', format= ',.0f')],
        color=alt.Color('bill_month', legend=None)
    ).properties(width=485,
                 title = alt.TitleParams(text = 'Bottom Components', 
                                         font = 'Arial', 
                                         fontSize = 16, 
                                         color = '#000080', 
                                        )
                ).interactive()
```

X axis label generated by this chart contains repeated 0 and  1
Image of Visualization: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0XdWB.png

Comment: Could you please provide an [mre]? The current code and data does not match up and there are undefined variables in your code (`mes`, `mesname`, `ClaimRuleName`)

Comment: Updated the code snippet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason this is happening is because you have `format= ',.0f'` which tells Altair to include 0 decimals in the axis labels. Remove it or change to `1f` to see decimals in the labels. In general, a good way to troubleshoot problems like this is to remove part of your code at a time to identify which part is causing the unexpected behavior.

To reduce the number of ticks you can use `alt.Axis(title='Flagged Claims', format='d', tickCount=1)` or `alt.Axis(title='Flagged Claims', format='d', values=[0, 1])`. See also [Changing Number of y-axis Ticks in Altair](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70816564/changing-number-of-y-axis-ticks-in-altair)

Comment: It resolves the issue partially as it shows decimal values. But don't we have provision to show integer values on labels as well.

Comment: Instead of repeated zeros and ones can't we have only one zero and one integer value. As flagged claims is a count and it can never be a decimal value. Since this chart is generated dynamically at runtime, it can have different measures and formats. But for this specific case it is integer.

Comment: @kanishkakartikeya Oh I see, I didn't get that from your original question. I updated my answer with a suggestion